# XScreenSaver lag when pressing Shift

Tags: linux, x11, keyboard, debugging, void-linux

I use Void Linux with kernel version 5.12.13 and LXQt and would like to use XScreenSaver 6.01 to lock my screen.

However, it's quite difficult to write my password on the `xscreensaver-auth` screen as XScreenSaver is lagging every time I use the Shift key to write in uppercase. Let me give you more information: when the screen saver is displayed, I press a key to get the password prompt. A first lag of circa 5 seconds happens. (It don't know if this one is related to the others.) I can put a lowercase password without a problem, but as soon as I press Shift (or the caps lock key), my PC (the display and also the mouse) lags for circa 5 seconds before allowing me to enter uppercase keys. The same phenomenon happens when I release the Shift key (or disable the caps lock key).

There's likely a bug in one process or another, but I cannot identify the bug. It doesn't seem to be related to my keyboard layout (a french one) as it does the same with the US keyboard. Outside XScreenSaver, Shift and caps lock keys are working fine. I am not having any problem with my graphic card which is displaying the screen savers well.

Here's an extract of what is written when I launch `xscreensaver` with the `--verbose` option:

```
xscreensaver-auth: 19:50:34: initial effective uid/gid was root/user (0/1000)
xscreensaver-auth: 19:50:34: changed uid/gid to user/user (1000/1000)
xscreensaver-auth: 19:50:34: running as user "user"
xscreensaver-auth: 19:50:34: PAM: pam_start ("xscreensaver", "user", ...) ==> 0 (Succès)
xscreensaver-auth: 19:50:34:   pam_set_item (p, PAM_TTY, ":0") ==> 0 (Succès)
xscreensaver-auth: 19:50:34:   pam_authenticate (...) ...
xscreensaver-auth: 19:50:34:     pam_conversation (ECHO_OFF="Mot de passe : ") ...
xscreensaver-auth: 19:50:34: theme: default
xscreensaver-auth: 19:50:38: kbd layout: French
xscreensaver-auth: 19:50:38: mouse is at 719,577 on monitor 0 1600x900+0+0 "eDP1"
xscreensaver-auth: 19:50:38: re-creating window: size changed
xscreensaver-auth: 19:50:39: XI RawKeyPress  
xscreensaver-auth: 19:50:39: XKB event 2
xscreensaver-auth: 19:50:43: kbd layout: French
xscreensaver-auth: 19:50:44: XI RawKeyPress  
xscreensaver-auth: 19:50:44: XI RawKeyRelease
xscreensaver-auth: 19:50:44: XI RawKeyPress  
xscreensaver-auth: 19:50:44: XI RawKeyRelease
xscreensaver-auth: 19:50:44: XI RawKeyPress  
xscreensaver-auth: 19:50:44: XI RawKeyRelease
xscreensaver-auth: 19:50:45: XI RawKeyPress  
xscreensaver-auth: 19:50:45: XI RawKeyRelease
xscreensaver-auth: 19:50:45: XI RawKeyPress  
xscreensaver-auth: 19:50:45: XI RawKeyRelease
xscreensaver-auth: 19:50:45: XI RawKeyRelease
xscreensaver-auth: 19:50:45: XKB event 2
xscreensaver-auth: 19:50:49: kbd layout: French
```

At 19:50:39, I press the Shift key, and at 19:50:45, I release it.

System logging is enabled with help of [this](https://docs.voidlinux.org/config/services/logging.html) page, but `svlogtail` doesn't display anything during the lags.

`/var/log/Xorg.0.log` --- this is displayed after I launch the screen saver:

```
[ 18271.902] (EE) event5  - Logitech M215: client bug: event processing lagging behind by 4021ms, your system is too slow
[ 18271.902] (EE) client bug: timer event5 debounce: scheduled expiry is in the past (-3996ms), your system is too slow
[ 18271.902] (EE) client bug: timer event5 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-4009ms), your system is too slow
[ 18280.862] (II) event0  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: SYN_DROPPED event - some input events have been lost.
[ 18302.431] (II) event0  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: SYN_DROPPED event - some input events have been lost.
```

`Logitech M215` is my mouse.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I observe similar problem on Debian Bookworm, `xscreensaver` Version 6.02+dfsg1-2. That's not a 5 second delay, it's in milisecond-range, but it's enough that `xscreensaver` repeatedly drops my uppercase password letter which annoys me much.
This didn't happen on 5.45.

Other talking places:
https://github.com/Zygo/xscreensaver/issues/11

That's probably caused by `xinput.c`, `xinput_event_to_xlib_1`, which has comment explaining races:

```
The closest thing to actual documentation on XInput2 seems to be a series
of blog posts by Peter Hutterer.  There's basically nothing about it on
www.x.org.  In http://who-t.blogspot.com/2009/07/xi2-recipes-part-4.html
he says: 

  "XIDeviceEvent [...] contains the state of the modifier keys [...]
  The base modifiers are the ones currently pressed, latched the ones
  pressed until a key is pressed that's configured to unlatch it (e.g.
  some shift-capslock interactions have this behaviour) and finally
  locked modifiers are the ones permanently active until unlocked
  (default capslock behaviour in the US layout). The effective modifiers
  are a bitwise OR of the three above - which is essentially equivalent
  to the modifiers state supplied in the core protocol events."

However, I'm seeing random noise in the various XIDeviceEvent.mods fields.
Nonsensical values like base = 0x6045FB3D.  So, let's poll the actual
modifiers from XQueryPointer.  This can race: maybe the modifier state
changed between when the server generated the keyboard event, and when
we receive it and poll.  However, if an actual human is typing and
releasing their modifier keys on such a tight timeframe... that's
probably already not going well.

I'm also seeing random noise in the event_xy and root_xy fields in
motion events.  So just always use XQueryPointer.
```

I have keyboard with "tap layer" and that explains 'tight timeframe'

Edit:
After some debugging and exchanging few emails with Jamie Zawinski (xscreensaver author) I've fixed the issue (for me) by patching the `duplicate_xinput_event_p` in the `xinput.c`. It might get fixed upstream in a similar or a different way. In the meanwhile, I'll publish the patch on the linked github (seems to large to post it here).